# ASIHTTPRequest and http header

Tags: iphone, asihttprequest

i would like to reproduce this http header call with ASIHTTPRequest. how i can do this please ??

```
Host www.host

User-Agent Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; fr; rv:1.9.2.17) Gecko/20110420 Firefox/3.6.17

Accept text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8

Accept-Language fr,fr-fr;q=0.8,en-us;q=0.5,en;q=0.3

Accept-Encoding gzip,deflate

Accept-Charset ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7

Keep-Alive 115

Proxy-Connection keep-alive

Cookie fe_typo_user=71
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can add request headers like this :

```
[request addRequestHeader:@"Referer" value:@"http://allseeing-i.com/"];
```